# Connecting to SQL-Azure with freeTDS error: Read from the server failed

Tags: t-sql, azure-sql-database, ubuntu-12.04, freetds

I'm trying to a SQl-Azure database from ubuntu 12.04.

I've downloaded freeTDS-0.91 and compiled it with openssl and libiconf (for use with the tiny_tds gem).

When I try connect to the sql-azure db I get the following error:

```
martinr@martinr-DT:~/code/psg-web$ tsql -U Username -P Password -H servername.database.windows.net -p 1433
locale is "en_ZA.UTF-8"
locale charset is "UTF-8"
using default charset "UTF-8"
Error 20004 (severity 9):
    Read from the server failed
OS error 104, "Connection reset by peer"
Error 20002 (severity 9):
    Adaptive Server connection failed
There was a problem connecting to the server
```

I can't seem to find anything on what is causing this error, and how to resolve it.

I can connect to instances of ms-sqlserver on a windows-server machine in the office without any problems.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?  I'm having the exact same problem now

Comment: We did but I can't remember our exact solution. From what I can remember make sure you can telnet to the server and follow the debug instructions in the documentation very carefully. http://www.freetds.org/userguide/serverthere.htm sorry I can't be of more help

Answer (score 3):

For azure sql use protocol version 8.0 (or 7.x). You can force it by:

```
TDSVER=8.0 tsql -U Username@servername -P Password -H servername.database.windows.net -p 1433
```

Comment: I found that Azure SQL (in V12 mode) works with freetds 0.91 when TDSVER is set to 8.0 or 7.1, *not* 7.2.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work using this [post](http://metaskills.net/2009/09/05/the-ultimate-os-x-snow-leopard-stack-for-rails-development-x86_64-macports-ruby-1-8-1-9-sql-server-more/).  Be sure to follow the instructions up till the part titled *Going The Extra Mile With Ruby 1.9.x* unless you've been using ruby 1.8 and are now goin to use 1.9.  In a later [post](http://metaskills.net/2010/07/19/a-macport-rubyodbc-update/) the author said to leave off the *+utf8* when running *sudo port install rb-odbc +utf8* as he instructed in his first post.

You can test the connection using *isql* like so:

```
isql server Username Password
```

For *server* enter the name you put in brackets in the odbc.ini file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, my issue is not with connecting to mssqlserver but with sql-azure. I can connect perfectly to an evaluation copy of sqlserver running on a windows server machine I've setup. My problem is connecting to sql-azure.